# Add a CSS Class to each Vertix in MXGRAPH

Tags: mxgraph

I would like to add a CSS Class to each Vertix in MXGRAPH, to be able to add style in an external theme. How could be possible?

I found only method to add `fillColor`, `gradientColor`, `stroke`, activate `rounded corners` but not to link them with CSS.

Comment: Not possible on vertices themselves, but you could enable HTML labels and use the label to render arbitary HTML/CSS

Comment: uhmmm I'll investigate about this solution but anyway is not what I need... I'd like to simplify styiling of vertices (current JS embedded implementation is hard to manage and documentation is not so clear)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 levels of customization you can do in mxgraph :

- the "mxgGraph" shapes, as you discovered with `fillColor` etc.
- using HTML labels

In my case, I ended up doing a mix of both: I customize the shape itself with mxGraph "native" features so that they render fast and well in the outline (mini-map) too; and then I refine my labels with HTML / CSS. For example, I have added markdown support, I have created a fairly advanced text editor for the boxes, etc.

At render time, I check the style name (and other properties) of the current mxCell object and I know which custom CSS class to add when rendering the html label.